# Reading Inconsistent Nested JSON in Athena

Tags: json, hive, nested, ddl, amazon-athena

In Athena, I am reading some nested JSON files into a table. The field that actually contains the nested JSON has an inconsistent number of fields within it across the different files in the raw data.

Sometimes the data looks something like this:

```
    {
          "id": "9f1e07b4",
          "date": "05/20/2018 02:30:53.110 AM",
          "data": {
            "a": "asd",
            "b": "adf",
            "body": {
              "sid": {
                "uif": "yes",
                "sidd": "no",
                "state": "idle"
              }
            },
            "category": "scene"
          }
        }
```

Other times the data looks something like this:

```
    {
  "id": "9f1e07b4",
  "date": "05/20/2018 02:30:45.436 AM",
  "data": {
    "a": "event",
    "b": "state",
    "body": {
      "persona": {
        "one": {
          "movement": "idle"
        }
      }
    },
    "category": "scene"
  }
}
```

Other times the "body" field contains both the "sid" struct and the "persona" struct.

As you can see the fields given within "body" are not always consistent. I tried to add all of the possible fields and their structures within my CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE query. However, the "data" column that contains the "body" field still does not fill and remains blank when I "preview table" in Athena.

In the CREATE TABLE DDL, is there a way to indicate that I want to fill all of columns that aren't present in the nested JSON of each file with null values?

Furthermore, the 'names' given to the fields in the query do not have to correspond to the key values in the raw JSON. It seems Athena is simply reading the structure and nothing else. Is there a way to indicate which JSON key corresponds to which Athena field name directly? So that if some fields are missing from the "body" of one file, Athena can know which one is missing and fill it in as null?